# SWT: Table with cells that span columns

Tags: java, ubuntu, swt

In a Java desktop app with SWT-based GUI, we have a table in which some rows must span multiple columns. This was solved with the approach shown in this official SWT Snippet: [Snippet239.java](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet239.java)

However, much later it was discovered that there's a major problem with this approach on Ubuntu with the default Ambiance/Radiance theme: There are always vertical lines between the columns, even for cells that span multiple columns. This is shown in the following screenshots:

[image: Ubuntu with Ambiance/Radiance theme]

[image: Ubuntu with Clearlooks theme]

As you can see, in the first screenshot there's a vertical line between Column 1 and Column 2. Does anybody have an idea how to get rid of these lines?

We've already tried the following:

- `Table.setLinesVisible(false)`: Doesn't work, the vertical lines don't go away.
- Use owner-draw-based label providers to draw over those vertical lines: Doesn't work, the vertical lines seem to be drawn on top of everything that is drawn by the label providers.
- Attach paint listener to table to draw over the vertical lines: Doesn't work, because there are lots of glitches whenever the table is scrolled or otherwise updated.
- The [Nebula project](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/) has a Grid widget where cells can span multiple columns, and it doesn't have a problem with vertical lines, because the entire table is drawn non-natively. However, we can't justify the effort to replace our table with a Grid widget just to fix the vertical lines problem on a particular platform with certain themes. Also, the Grid widget seems to be a pre-release alpha version.

Based on the things we've already tried, I assume the only way left is to muck around in the platform-specific internals of SWT, but I don't even know where to start with something like that.

Comment: Sounds like this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=138909 which doesn't see to have much movement on it. One thing you should do, as well as looking at workarounds, is to bump this bug.

Comment: Is this the same method you meant by setLinesVisible? table.setShowGrid(false);

Comment: @Logan: The SWT Table widget doesn't have a setShowGrid method, AFAIK. Perhaps you mean the JTable from Swing?

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry about that. I always get those mixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this problem by using a `Table` with a single owner-draw column that emulates multiple columns.